# Object function scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

`factory(n)` returns objects with functions.
`func1` function definition creates its own scope, and `x` inside this function references `x = n + ''`.
But `func2` is a reference and the scope is wrong.

Is there a way to return an object from `create` so its functions were references (not separate definitions)?

Actually, I'm fine with `func1` approach while function definition footprint is small. If it is a complex function it would be better not to clone this function into every object comming from `factory(n)`. `inner_func` may not use `this`, it is simple function. Also I want to avoid `new` and `this`.

```js
var factory = (function(){
  var x = '!';

  return function create(n){
    var x = n + '';
    return {
      func1: function(y){return inner_func(x, y); },
      /* vs */
      func2: inner_func_api
    }
  }

  function inner_func_api(y){ return inner_func(x, y); }

  function inner_func(a, b){ return a + b; }

}());

var f1 = factory(2);
var f2 = factory(3);

var f1_func1 = f1.func1(4);
var f2_func1 = f2.func1(5);

var f1_func2 = f1.func2(4);
var f2_func2 = f2.func2(5);

console.log(f1_func1, f2_func1); //24 35
console.log(f1_func2, f2_func2); //!4 !5
```

Comment: using new and prototypes is the built in way to do this. I know Crockford doesn't like it. But that is the languages mechanism to do what you are trying to do. Your `func2` approach is good and uses references as functions.

Comment: I'm not entire sure what you're asking. You either need to a closure to capture state, or you need to pass parameters. Depending on what you're actually doing you might be able to use partial application and avoid an *entire* duplicated function, but you'll still need to get the state you need either through closures or params. As t3dodson says, "avoiding" `new` and `this` effectively eliminates a good chunk of JS's OOP capabilities--what's the rational for dropping what JS gives you?

Comment: May be it was too strict. I want to add, `this, prototype, bind, call` inside `func1, func2, inner_func_api` are ok. As to OOP, I want to minimize managing states. Don't you think, the code looks beautiful without `this` and `new` :),  and simpler. As I said, the solution does the job; I just wanted a little improve and thought I was missing something for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* define that function separately from the object initializer on the `return` statement:

```
var factory = (function(){
  var x = '!';

  return function create(n){
    var x = n + '';

    function func1(y) {
      return inner_func(x, y);
    }

    return {
      func1: func1,
      /* vs */
      func2: inner_func_api
    }
  }

  function inner_func_api(y){ return inner_func(x, y); }

  function inner_func(a, b){ return a + b; }

}());
```

However, it makes no practical difference, and it doesn't matter how big or complicated that function is. Function instances do take up space, but the code for the function is constant (immutable) and doesn't need to be part of every Function object created from the same piece of source code.